# Videoplayer which supoorts all file format and with social sharing option

Tags: video-player

I wanted to create a videoplayer for my website and have done with silverlight but it supports the mpeg4 format either wmv,avi ,flv are not supported , so found another player like videojs but then it didnt have option for socioal sharing like fb or to share the embed , so please advice to find a player which supports max file format and with sharing option ,

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: I wouldn't use a videplayer supporting all formats. I suggest you use a converter that converts any type of video to flv, and then stream your vids as flv.

Answer (score 1):

I think http://www.projekktor.com/
is exactly what you're looking for.

You can use the share add-on for social functionality